# Can I use a vxWorks boot loader to load a vxWorks image of a different version

Tags: vxworks

I've got a board with an old VxWorks 6.5 boot loader loading an image over ftp.  If I put a new image on ftp built for VxWroks 6.7 (or higher) should that work.  My tests so far seem to indicate no.  However, I don't yet trust that my new kernel's are good.

EDIT:
To troubleshoot I built a VxWorks 6.7 boot loader and made a new boot floppy.  The first problem I have is that my VxWorks image is crashing somewhere in the board support package (BSP).  I've not gotten to the part where I tweak the configuration to load it with a 6.5 boot loader.  It looks like I'll be troubleshooting the BSP that came with the board for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that a 6.5 Bootloader works just fine with a 6.7 VxWorks image.

However, you have to make sure that the settings for the vxWorks image match the settings for the bootloader. The main ones being:

- RAM settings: RAM_HIGH/RAM_LOW, etc...
- sysPhysMemTop(),
- BOOTLINE address

Matching RAM configuration is important if you use the ED&R framework.